# Como tratar a string para evitar SQL Injection?

Tags: php, sql

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$ip = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\.]/", "", $_POST['ip']);
$porta = preg_replace("/[^0-9\s]/", "", $_POST['porta']);
$site = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\.]/", "", $_POST['site']);
```

Estou tratando algumas variáveis com exceção de uma, pois ela precisa aceitar acentuação, como eu faço o tratamento dessa variável corretamente pra evitar `SQL Injection`? E fazer com que ela aceite acentuação, traços e colchetes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o `mysql_real_escape_string` ([Documentação](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php))

Essa função não vai te fazer perder os caracteres indesejados, como da forma que você está fazendeo. Eles serão codificados, de forma que o MYSQL os entenda como parte da `string`, e não parte do código.

Answer (score 7):

Vale informar que **[mysql_real_escape_string](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)** está **OBSOLETA** (veja na documentação em inglês)!

> Warning
>   This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more information.
>
> Alternatives to this function include:
>
> mysqli_real_escape_string()
>
> PDO::quote()

Recomendo que utilize **[PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.pdo.php)** ou **[mysqli](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqli.php)**, sempre com com `prepare`.

Já existe uma excelente reposta do @rray sobre esse assunto: **[Como prevenir injeção de código SQL no meu código PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/3869/31016)**